# "Our office was left early" – how do I say this naturally?

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, phrasal-verbs

Plesase help me with below sentence construction.

> Yesterday our office was left early because of heavy rain

Suggest me synonyms for *left* or any alternative sentence. 
I feel use of Past tense *leave* i.e. *left* is incorrect.

(From a comment:) I want to say boss allowed us to leave early from office. He closed the office early.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where active voice is simpler than passive voice.  In American English, it is normal for an "office" to be the subject of a sentence like this:

> 2. Yesterday, our office closed early because of heavy rain.

"Because of" can be shortened to "due to".

In sentence #2, "early" is relative to the normal closing time for "our office".

The following sentence is not as good as sentence #2:

> 3. Our office closed early yesterday because of heavy rain.

The problem with sentence #3 is that it is unclear whether "early" is in the context of a "workday" (like for an office) or a "day" (such as "yesterday").  Early in a "day" can be much earlier than early in a "workday".

Comment: Note that you can also use the passive voice with #2: "Yesterday, our office was closed early..."  This can emphasize a bit more strongly that somebody (the boss) was deliberately doing the closing (as opposed to just an automatic thing that came about because of some office policy or some such)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *leave* has two meanings:

- you separate yourself from a place (I left the park)
- you separate an object you have from your possession, accidentally or intentionally (I left my keys in the car)

Using this passively might swing the listener/reader toward assuming the second meaning or considering it for a brief moment and having to think about what the sentence says.

There's no good simple word to substitute that only means the first meaning.  *Vacate* is probably the closest but this has strong connotations of a serious emergency (like bomb threat) so you don't want to use that.

So *closed* is better, because that's more along what the office is, rather than what people in it are doing.

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to convey? *...office was left early...* can be written in a better way.

Probably, you want to say...

> *Yesterday, we left office early due to heavy rain*

'left' **is** the correct word.

Be cautious! Adding a little preposition would mean something completely different!

> *Yesterday, we left **for** office early due to have rain.*

Here, you reached office early!

Comment: I want to say boss allowed us to leave early from office. He colsed the office early.

Comment: Does not make any difference...you still say: *We left the office quite early due to heavy rain.*

Comment: Another option would be _Yesterday the office closed early due to heavy rain._

Comment: @MaulikV -- Technically, your second example says you "left for [the] office early".  It does not say whether you arrived early, on time, or late.  You might not have reached the office at all!

Comment: @Jasper technicality is regretted.